# How to interrogate UIUserNotificationSettings types

Tags: ios, objective-c, permissions, notifications, ios8

I am trying to implement the `application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:` App Delegate method to try and identify if i am allowed to send local notifications to the user in iOS 8. The following is the kind of thing i'm trying to achieve, but this is obviously the incorrect way of going about it.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{

    if (notificationSettings.types /*How do i check which types are contained */) {

        NSLog(@"Allowed");

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Not Allowed");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here you go

```
if (notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone) {
      NSlog(@"Permission not Granted by user");
}
else{
      NSlog(@"Permission Granted");
}
```

To interrogate a specific setting:

```
BOOL allowsSound = (notifSettings.types & UIUserNotificationTypeSound) != 0;
```

Comment: Simple, thanks... I'll accept the answer in 11 minutes (when i'm allowed to!)

Comment: Ok so, how do i tell if permission is granted, but not for sounds? This doesn't work: `if (notifSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeSound)`

Comment: Ahh, okay... Like this: `BOOL allowsSound = (notifSettings.types & UIUserNotificationTypeSound) != 0;`
`

Comment: Would anyone be able to provide the Swift equivalent to this? I'm having a hard time getting the above to work. Xcode 6.1. `(notificationSettings.types & UIUserNotificationType.Badge)` produces UIUserNotificationType is not convertible to 'Bool'

Comment: Swift version:
let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound

Comment: The above should work in Swift also, I think Matt just forgot the "!= 0" part.  Cymric's comment shows how to set types, but the code in the answer should work in both languages, for checking.